# Crash during program startup when linking against Boost regex library

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker

Our project (in C++) needs to link against `boost regex` so we just locate the correct compiled `libboost_regex_1.45.0` and tell g++ to link against it. Compiling is successful and we just get the right executable as expected. The problem is, each time we try to run the executable, it crashes before entering `main()` routine.

Attaching the generated `core` file with `gdb`, the `backtrace` command shows there's a segmentation fault during `__bultin_strlen`, which is resolved to `strlen@@GLBC_2.2.5`.

Since our executable is linked against several dynamic libraries, `readelf -s` is harnessed to identify the problematic symbol and it boils down to `libboost_regex`. However the referred symbol is already there in RHEL6 system folder `/lib64/libc.so`.

The question is, how can we get boost regex working properly?

- OS: RHEL6.2
- GCC: 4.3.2 / `libstdc++6.0.13`
- Boost libraries is built by exactly the same toolset - `user-config.bjam` is customized

Static linking is not a good choice for us for various reasons.

The symbol info and ldd info is attached at https://gist.github.com/skyscribe/5184622

Comment: Have you looked at the complete backtrace? There's no constructor or static initialization of yours that is running?

Comment: First make sure the compiler versions used to build your program and boost_regex match. Have you compiled boost from source, or did you install a precompiled version?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, the backtrace just points to boost regex library - some RAII stuffs specific to Boost library's detail namespace, irrelevant with application logic. Even a very simple hello world program may crash, as long as this library is linked. Other libraries work fine though, like `libboost_thread`, which doesn't refer to symbols like `xxx@@GLIBC_2.2.5`

Comment: @Axel Yes, we tried building boost libraries with the same compiler toolset - we have to do that since RHEL ships with GCC4.4.6 while we have to stick to 4.3.2.

Comment: Please post the traceback verbatim, and the output of `ldd /path/to/libboost_regex.so`.

Comment: Please show line 28 (and the surrounding lines) of the file `test.cpp`. That's the origin of the crash, and inside your `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

From the gdb backtrace, we see that the `std::char_traits<char>::length` method with argument `\"http:\\\\/\\\\/localhostr.com\\\\/files\\\\/.+?\"` is triggering the segmentation fault. g++ 4.3.2 introduced new [Stack Smashing Protection](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-09/Fritsch/Blackhat-Europe-2009-Fritsch-Bypassing-aslr-slides.pdf) features, which may interfere with the strlen length computation.

Recompile/relink your code with a recent g++ compiler and see if you solve this error. This sample code does not reproduce such error:

```
user@workstation ~
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.3-3/gcc4-4.5.3-3/src/gcc-4.5.3/configure --srcdir=/gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.3-3/gcc4-4.5.3-3/src/gcc-4.5.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/lib --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc4 -C --datadir=/usr/share --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man -v --with-gmp=/usr --with-mpfr=/usr --enable-bootstrap --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-lto --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-symvers --enable-libjava --program-suffix=-4 --enable-libgomp --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-threads=posix --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-libgcj-sublibs CC=gcc-4 CXX=g++-4 CC_FOR_TARGET=gcc-4 CXX_FOR_TARGET=g++-4 GNATMAKE_FOR_TARGET=gnatmake GNATBIND_FOR_TARGET=gnatbind --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.3 (GCC)

user@workstation ~
$ cat test.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char * a = "\"http:\\\\/\\\\/localhostr.com\\\\/files\\\\/.+?\"";
  int t =  std::char_traits<char>::length (a);
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

user@workstation ~
$ g++ -g test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:6:14: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

user@workstation ~
$ gdb a.exe
Reading symbols from /home/user/a.exe...done.
(gdb) b std::char_traits<char>::length
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4017f6: file /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h, line 263.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/a.exe
[New Thread 764.0x5e4]
[New Thread 764.0x100c]

Breakpoint 1, std::char_traits<char>::length (__s=0x402080 "\"http:\\\\/\\\\/localhostr.com\\\\/files\\\\/.+?\"") at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:263
263           { return __builtin_strlen(__s); }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
41
[Inferior 1 (process 764) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: Don't think this is the same issue - because of third-party libraries' dependency on GCC version, it's risky to replace the GCC compiler version for me. Thanks for the comment anyway.